# Why does a tkinter GUI behave differently when run as an .exe (created via pyinstaller)?

Tags: tkinter, focus, pyinstaller

I have a GUI created with `tkinter` that is transparent.

```
import tkinter as tkinter 

class TransparentWindow(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):

         # Initialize the mainframe and declare the master
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # Make the window transparent
        transparent = self.set_transparent_color(
            window = self.master,
            color = "yellow"
            )
        self.master["bg"] = transparent

        self.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)

    def set_transparent_color(self, window, color):
        """
        Mark a sacraficial color as transparent for a window.
        """
        window.wm_attributes(
            "-transparentcolor",
            color
            )
        return color


# Create window
root_window = tkinter.Tk()
TransparentWindow(root_window)
root_window.mainloop()
```

When I run this as a `.py` file, the window appears and stays above all other windows (due to the `-topmost` attribute).  This window can be "clicked through".  That is to say that you can click inside the window, and interact with the immediate window behind it.  The transparent window will lose focus, but remain above the other window.

Now, when this code is compiled into an executable via the `pyinstaller` command: `pyinstaller --onefile -w script_name.py` and that executable is run, the transparent window will not lose focus if you click inside of it.

Why would the same code when run as a `.py` vs `.exe` alter the behavior of focus like this?  Is this a `pyinstaller` thing, or do `tkinter` GUIs necessarily behave differently for some reason?

Comment: Under w7 python 3.8 i can't interact with the window behind also without pyinstaller.

Comment: What version of `pyinstaller` are you using? This seems to have been fixed in the version `4.2`, make sure that you have the updated version, you may execute `pip install --upgrade pyinstaller` and then try it out.

Comment: @AST This solved the matter.  Lesson learned: Always verify that your imported modules are the latest versions!  Thank you very much.  If you answer the question, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following has been fixed in version `4.2` with the commit [`3c3228d`](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/commit/3c3228da89c494f79dc1cead99ab9b4e45a7424e). The issue persists if `icon` is set to `NONE`, currently reported as a [bug](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5624). This along with other issues that arise are likely to be fixed in the near future.

Use the following command to update `pyinstaller`

```
pip install --upgrade pyinstaller
```